# Creating A Second Object From A Class

Tags: php, class, object

Can someone lead me in the right direction to create a second object from the Dog class called $chow & call the speak method to make him ‘bark’.

```
<?php
class Dog
{
    private $dog_weight = 0;
    private $dog_breed = "no breed";
    private $dog_color = "no color";
    private $dog_name = "no name";
    public  $speak = "bark";

function display_properties()
{

    print "Dog weight is $this->dog_weight. Dog breed is $this->dog_breed. Dog color is $this->dog_color.";

}
public function bark()
{       

    print "Woof, woof!";            

}
}
?>




<?php
require_once('e34dog.php');
$lab = new Dog;
$lab->display_properties();
$lab->bark();
?>
```

Comment: Are you meaning add $chow->bark(); if so when i previously did that I received the following error: Dog weight is 0. Dog breed is no breed. Dog color is no color.Woof, woof!
Notice: Undefined variable: chow in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Assignment 8\e35labChow2.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function bark() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Assignment 8\e35labChow2.php on line 6

Comment: before calling bark you may want to initialize $chow, the same way you have initialized $lab :)

Comment: $chow = new Dog; similar to $lab initialised it

Comment: before you write `$chow->bark();` make sure you have created the instance `$chow = new Dog();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
$chow = new Dog();
$chow->bark();
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Yes ! You totally understood me ! Ive been looking at it for so long I just couldnt quite wrap my head around what was missing... smh ... simple things lol Thank You Sooo Much !

Comment: @BaBarMiamor accept his answer if it solved your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect it to act different since its an instance of `Dog` class.

```
<?php
require_once('e34dog.php');
$lab = new Dog;
$lab->display_properties();
$lab->bark();
$chow = new Dog;
$chow->bark();
?>
```